# grep the lines of file using for loop

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, grep, cd

There is a file and each line shows the different file paths.

````
    ```
      my_file
      /the/first/path/file1
      /the/second/path/file2
      ....
    ```
````

I want to use for loop to find a string in each file.

````
     ```
      for i in $(cat my_file); do cd "$i"; done | grep -w string "$i"

     ```
````

But this seems not working for me. I am getting this for all file directory

```
    -bash: cd: /the/first/path/file1: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for a `for` loop, use `xargs`:

```
xargs -a my_file -d '\n' grep -h -w string
```

Note #1: I added the `-h` option (GNU extension) so that the filenames are not added by `grep` in the output (like in your command).

Note #2: since you are using Linux and Bash, I'm assuming GNU `xargs`. If your `xargs` does not understand the `-a` option, then use this instead:

```
< my_file xargs -d '\n' grep -h -w string
```

Comment: Thanks but still having same problem  "grep: /the/first/path/file1: No such file or directory". When I try to search it individually:   <  zgrep string ~/the/first/path/file1 >  it works. Weird, don't know what's wrong

Comment: The file doesn't exist, there is nothing I can do about it. If the file existed, you'd see that my command works and not yours.

Comment: Your example that works uses ~/the/first/path/file1. Your example that doesn’t used /the/first/path/file1.  ~ means your home directory. / means the root of the file system. Completely different things.

Comment: Good catch @NicholasRees!